# How to change matplotlib marker into a football icon?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, google-maps-markers

I have visualization like this:

[image]

I want to change the marker icon into a **football icon** with the **same color as the line**

My code looks like this :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

ax.step(x = a_df['minute'], y = a_df['a_cum'], where = 'post', label= ateam, linewidth=2)
ax.step(x = h_df['minute'], y = h_df['h_cum'], where = 'post', color ='red', label= hteam,linewidth=2)  

plt.scatter(x= a_goal['minute'], y = a_goal['a_cum'] , marker = 'o')
plt.scatter(x= h_goal['minute'], y = h_goal['h_cum'] , marker = 'o',color = 'red')

plt.xticks([0,15,30,45,60,75,90])
plt.yticks([0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3])
plt.grid()

ax.title.set_text('The Expected Goals(xG) Chart Final Champions League 2010/2011')
plt.ylabel("Expected Goals (xG)")
plt.xlabel("Minutes")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I don't have any clue to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `matplotlib` can draw custom markers. Therefore, I suggest the way to draw is to use the **football image** as a **marker** with the given coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

def getImage(path):
   return OffsetImage(plt.imread(path), zoom=.02)
x_coords = [8.2, 4.5, 3.3, 6.9]
y_coords = [5.4, 3.5, 4.7, 7.1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for x0, y0 in zip(x_coords, y_coords):
   ab = AnnotationBbox(getImage('football_icon.png'), (x0, y0), frameon=False)
   ax.add_artist(ab)
   
plt.xticks(range(10))
plt.yticks(range(10))
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: just to note matplotlib can use custom latex symbols or unicode characters as markers, as long as the font you are using supports it. So you could use `marker='$\u26bd$' for example to get a football ⚽. But your option works perfectly well too

Comment: Thank for your useful information.

Answer (score 2):

you can draw your own shapes by creating matplotlib Path objects.
You need 2 lists to create it.
1)shape's vertices(coordinates)
2)codes:describes the path from a vertice to the next (MOVETO,LINETO,CURVE3,CURVE4,CLOSEPOLY,...)

for example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path

vertices=[[ 1.86622681e+00, -9.69864442e+01], [-5.36324682e+01, -9.69864442e+01],
 [-9.86337733e+01, -5.19851396e+01], [-9.86337733e+01,  3.51356038e+00],
 [-9.86337733e+01,  5.90122504e+01], [-5.36324682e+01, 1.04013560e+02],
 [ 1.86622681e+00, 1.04013560e+02], [ 5.73649168e+01,  1.04013560e+02],
 [ 1.02366227e+02,  5.90122504e+01], [ 1.02366227e+02,  3.51356038e+00],
 [ 1.02366227e+02, -5.19851396e+01], [ 5.73649168e+01, -9.69864442e+01],
 [ 1.86622681e+00, -9.69864442e+01], [ 1.86622681e+00, -9.69864442e+01],
 [ 1.86622681e+00, -9.69864442e+01], [ 1.86622681e+00, -9.59864442e+01], 
 [ 1.49396568e+01, -9.59864442e+01], [ 2.74005268e+01, -9.34457032e+01],
 [ 3.88349768e+01, -8.88614442e+01], [ 3.93477668e+01, -8.39473616e+01],
 [ 3.91766768e+01, -7.84211406e+01], [ 3.83349768e+01, -7.24551946e+01],
 [ 2.54705168e+01, -7.17582316e+01], [ 1.38598668e+01, -6.91771276e+01],
 [ 3.49122681e+00, -6.47364446e+01], [-5.88483119e+00, -7.07454276e+01],
 [-1.85084882e+01, -7.43878696e+01], [-3.31337732e+01, -7.44239446e+01],
 [-3.31639232e+01, -8.07006846e+01], [-3.34889082e+01, -8.56747886e+01],
 [-3.41025232e+01, -8.92676942e+01], [-2.29485092e+01, -9.35925582e+01],
 [-1.08166852e+01, -9.59864442e+01], [ 1.86622681e+00, -9.59864442e+01],
 [ 1.86622681e+00, -9.59864442e+01], [ 1.86622681e+00, -9.59864442e+01],
 [ 3.98974768e+01, -8.84239444e+01], [ 6.30273268e+01, -7.88377716e+01],
 [ 8.17782368e+01, -6.07995616e+01], [ 9.22412268e+01, -3.81426946e+01],
 [ 8.94287268e+01, -3.42676946e+01], [ 8.27048568e+01, -3.89413496e+01],
 [ 7.41977468e+01, -4.19580876e+01], [ 6.55537268e+01, -4.39551946e+01],
 [ 6.55507268e+01, -4.39600946e+01], [ 6.55258268e+01, -4.39502946e+01],
 [ 6.55225268e+01, -4.39551946e+01], [ 5.64622368e+01, -5.74584576e+01],
 [ 4.77347768e+01, -6.68825886e+01], [ 3.93037768e+01, -7.22051946e+01],
 [ 4.01409768e+01, -7.80795846e+01], [ 4.03596968e+01, -8.35092576e+01],
 [ 3.98975268e+01, -8.84239444e+01], [ 3.98974768e+01, -8.84239444e+01],
 [ 3.98974768e+01, -8.84239444e+01], [-3.33525232e+01, -7.34239446e+01],
 [-3.33343532e+01, -7.34304446e+01], [-3.33081932e+01, -7.34174446e+01],
 [-3.32900232e+01, -7.34239446e+01], [-1.87512102e+01, -7.34136546e+01],
 [-6.26111319e+00, -6.98403626e+01], [ 2.95997681e+00, -6.39239446e+01],
 [ 4.88356681e+00, -5.29429786e+01], [ 6.50358681e+00, -4.13393356e+01],
 [ 7.80372681e+00, -2.91114446e+01], [-8.09469019e+00, -1.58596306e+01],
 [-1.93481942e+01, -5.40333762e+00], [-2.47587732e+01,  1.32605538e+00],
 [-3.69631432e+01, -2.50275662e+00], [-4.85465082e+01, -5.39578762e+00],
 [-5.95087732e+01, -7.36144462e+00], [-6.28171902e+01, -1.66250136e+01],
 [-6.52187002e+01, -2.98372096e+01], [-6.58837732e+01, -4.57989446e+01],
 [-5.53582062e+01, -6.01863506e+01], [-4.45266302e+01, -6.94131916e+01],
 [-3.33525232e+01, -7.34239446e+01], [-3.33525232e+01, -7.34239446e+01],
 [-3.33525232e+01, -7.34239446e+01], [-7.57587732e+01, -4.67676946e+01],
 [-7.29041812e+01, -4.67440446e+01], [-6.99334012e+01, -4.63526666e+01],
 [-6.68837732e+01, -4.56426946e+01], [-6.62087282e+01, -2.96768106e+01],
 [-6.37905682e+01, -1.64255576e+01], [-6.04462732e+01, -7.04894462e+00],
 [-6.81326882e+01,  3.32535038e+00], [-7.26804032e+01,  1.40097104e+01],
 [-7.40712732e+01,  2.50135604e+01], [-7.99916232e+01,  2.63222104e+01],
 [-8.66133452e+01,  2.67559804e+01], [-9.31650233e+01,  2.54510604e+01],
 [-9.31681733e+01,  2.54460604e+01], [-9.31931223e+01,  2.54560604e+01],
 [-9.31962733e+01,  2.54510604e+01], [-9.44043873e+01,  2.37123804e+01],
 [-9.54279373e+01,  2.17334704e+01], [-9.63212733e+01,  1.95448104e+01],
 [-9.71662733e+01,  1.43262704e+01], [-9.76337733e+01,  8.97093038e+00],
 [-9.76337733e+01,  3.51356038e+00], [-9.76337733e+01, -1.43647536e+01],
 [-9.29174773e+01, -3.11438126e+01], [-8.46650232e+01, -4.56426946e+01],
 [-8.18063532e+01, -4.64180796e+01], [-7.88476312e+01, -4.67932816e+01],
 [-7.57587732e+01, -4.67676946e+01], [-7.57587732e+01, -4.67676946e+01],
 [-7.57587732e+01, -4.67676946e+01], [ 6.55224768e+01, -4.28926946e+01],
 [ 7.40107668e+01, -4.09146326e+01], [ 8.23640768e+01, -3.79999686e+01],
 [ 8.88662268e+01, -3.34864446e+01], [ 9.61553068e+01, -1.55950616e+01],
 [ 9.94808868e+01, -1.66158462e+00], [ 9.88662268e+01,  8.32606038e+00],
 [ 9.42289868e+01,  2.15752904e+01], [ 8.77410868e+01,  3.15965604e+01],
 [ 8.11474768e+01,  3.82010604e+01], [ 7.17659368e+01,  3.38334104e+01],
 [ 6.38899668e+01,  3.03415204e+01], [ 5.74912268e+01,  2.77635604e+01],
 [ 5.68036568e+01,  1.50717604e+01], [ 5.35581368e+01, -9.16606169e-02],
 [ 4.82412268e+01, -1.60489446e+01], [ 5.52234668e+01, -2.62259056e+01],
 [ 6.09897268e+01, -3.51652306e+01], [ 6.55224768e+01, -4.28926946e+01],
 [ 6.55224768e+01, -4.28926946e+01], [ 6.55224768e+01, -4.28926946e+01],
 [ 8.42872681e+00, -2.83614446e+01], [ 2.13772368e+01, -2.57261866e+01],
 [ 3.43239568e+01, -2.15154036e+01], [ 4.72724768e+01, -1.57364446e+01],
 [ 5.25849968e+01,  2.07647383e-01], [ 5.58247068e+01,  1.53619304e+01],
 [ 5.64912268e+01,  2.79510604e+01], [ 5.64917568e+01,  2.79612604e+01],
 [ 5.64906868e+01,  2.79721604e+01], [ 5.64912268e+01,  2.79822604e+01],
 [ 4.74302668e+01,  3.88992704e+01], [ 3.74260968e+01,  4.79380604e+01],
 [ 2.64912268e+01,  5.51072604e+01], [ 1.05529568e+01,  5.24508804e+01],
 [-4.02431919e+00,  4.78459804e+01], [-1.52900232e+01,  4.18885104e+01],
 [-1.91554652e+01,  2.63828404e+01], [-2.20678242e+01,  1.30703504e+01],
 [-2.40400232e+01,  1.98226038e+00], [-1.87588732e+01, -4.60782062e+00],
 [-7.49875919e+00, -1.50853886e+01], [ 8.42872681e+00, -2.83614946e+01],
 [ 8.42872681e+00, -2.83614446e+01], [ 8.42872681e+00, -2.83614446e+01],
 [ 9.97724768e+01,  8.82606038e+00], [ 1.01209977e+02,  9.29481038e+00],
 [ 9.97891268e+01,  3.41125404e+01], [ 8.92576668e+01,  5.64775904e+01],
 [ 7.29287268e+01,  7.31385604e+01], [ 7.01162268e+01,  7.01073104e+01],
 [ 7.65398468e+01,  5.90945204e+01], [ 8.04306168e+01,  4.87012104e+01],
 [ 8.18037268e+01,  3.89510604e+01], [ 8.85060268e+01,  3.22487504e+01],
 [ 9.50869868e+01,  2.21436404e+01], [ 9.97724768e+01,  8.82606038e+00],
 [ 9.97724768e+01,  8.82606038e+00], [ 9.97724768e+01,  8.82606038e+00],
 [-7.39150232e+01,  2.60448104e+01], [-6.92374072e+01,  3.77382804e+01],
 [-6.07391432e+01,  4.81501604e+01], [-4.84150232e+01,  5.72948104e+01],
 [-4.77543102e+01,  6.78197404e+01], [-4.56607662e+01,  7.76814004e+01],
 [-4.11025232e+01,  8.57010604e+01], [-4.52341512e+01,  8.65620704e+01],
 [-4.97579362e+01,  8.64646604e+01], [-5.46650232e+01,  8.53885604e+01],
 [-7.24317802e+01,  7.30970204e+01], [-8.60276902e+01,  5.51787904e+01],
 [-9.28212733e+01,  3.42010604e+01], [-9.28243733e+01,  3.41920604e+01],
 [-9.28181733e+01,  3.41792604e+01], [-9.28212733e+01,  3.41698604e+01],
 [-9.30130013e+01,  3.14875704e+01], [-9.31144113e+01,  2.89274504e+01],
 [-9.31337733e+01,  2.64511104e+01], [-8.65119202e+01,  2.77331304e+01],
 [-7.98647022e+01,  2.73522904e+01], [-7.39150232e+01,  2.60448604e+01],
 [-7.39150232e+01,  2.60448104e+01], [-7.39150232e+01,  2.60448104e+01],
 [-1.56650232e+01,  4.27948104e+01], [-4.35766519e+00,  4.87636404e+01],
 [ 1.01466668e+01,  5.33700304e+01], [ 2.60224768e+01,  5.60448104e+01],
 [ 2.85590568e+01,  6.43435004e+01], [ 3.07827468e+01,  7.29492504e+01],
 [ 3.27099768e+01,  8.18573104e+01], [ 2.55039768e+01,  9.03537704e+01],
 [ 1.39714968e+01,  9.64983204e+01], [-1.13376819e+00,  9.85135604e+01],
 [-1.57753392e+01,  9.71825004e+01], [-2.87516412e+01,  9.28553404e+01],
 [-4.00712732e+01,  8.55448104e+01], [-4.46513912e+01,  7.76614604e+01],
 [-4.67507882e+01,  6.78133804e+01], [-4.74150232e+01,  5.72323104e+01],
 [-3.59060892e+01,  5.27285604e+01], [-2.53218622e+01,  4.79159104e+01],
 [-1.56650232e+01,  4.27948104e+01], [-1.56650232e+01,  4.27948104e+01],
 [ 6.94599768e+01,  7.08573104e+01], [ 7.22412268e+01,  7.38573104e+01],
 [ 5.42332468e+01,  9.18657304e+01], [ 2.93485768e+01,  1.03013560e+02],
 [ 1.86622681e+00,  1.03013560e+02], [ 1.03891181e+00,  1.03013560e+02],
 [ 2.19951808e-01,  1.03002360e+02], [-6.02518192e-01,  1.02982360e+02],
 [-1.00876819e+00,  9.94823604e+01], [ 1.43154268e+01,  9.74387404e+01],
 [ 2.60994568e+01,  9.12180804e+01], [ 3.34912268e+01,  8.24823604e+01],
 [ 4.89375568e+01,  8.17496704e+01], [ 6.09313968e+01,  7.78789204e+01],
 [ 6.94599768e+01,  7.08573604e+01], [ 6.94599768e+01,  7.08573104e+01],
 [ 6.94599768e+01,  7.08573104e+01]]
codes=[1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,2,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,79,
1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,79,
1,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,2, 79]
print(Path.MOVETO,Path.LINETO,Path.CURVE3,Path.CURVE4,Path.CLOSEPOLY)
ball=Path(vertices,codes)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(15,1,color='b',marker=ball,markersize=30)
plt.xticks([0,15,30,45,60,75,90])
plt.yticks([0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3])
plt.grid()
ax.title.set_text('The Expected Goals(xG) Chart Final Champions League 2010/2011')
plt.ylabel("Expected Goals (xG)")
plt.xlabel("Minutes")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [**@tmdavison**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74664926/how-to-change-matplotlib-marker-into-a-football-icon/74665691#comments-74665691) said, `matplotlib` can use unicode characters, you just have to find a proper font. I use 'Segoe UI Symbol' (Yu Gothic & Segoe UI Emoji will also work) with such code:

```
ax.text(x = x,
        y = y, 
        s = u'\u26bd', 
        size = 20, 
        color = color, 
        fontfamily = 'Segoe UI Symbol')
```

works like a charm :)

Comment: If the character requires simple rendering, that would work. Many emoji require complex rendering, so it would also be necessary to change the matplotlib backend to mplcairo for rendering to be correct.